# alternate proof of theorem 1.21 of Baby Rudin

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I wanted to ask if anyone has tried to prove theorem 1.21 from Baby Rudin book (on existence and uniqueness of positive real n-th root of a positive real number) differently and would care to check my outline of alternative proof of the existence part in theorem 1.21. It is not really THAT different, I just use one of the earlier theorems in the chapter to obtain the key conclusion. Here is the outline:

Let x be a positive real number and n a positive integer. Let E be the set of all positive real numbers whose nth power is less than x, and B be the set of all positive real numbers whose nth power is greater than x.

1. Show that E and B are nonempty and bounded above and below, respectively.
2. Prove E is the set of all positive lower bounds of B.
3. Use Theorem 1.11 (that proves that an ordered set with the least upper bound property also has the greatest lower bound property) to show that y = sup E = inf B.
4. Conclude that y raised to nth power gives x.

I appreciate your comments.
ZK

Comment: Your approach is perfectly right. But there is no need to consider set B. You can do with set E and $\sup E$.

Comment: Thank you, but without B how would I be able to conclude that nth power of y is both greater than x and less than x?

Comment: you need to proceed in this fashion. Suppose $y^{n} < x$ and then try to show that there is a $z \in E$ with $y < z$. This means finding a $z$ such that $y^{n} < z^{n} < x$. Similarly consider the case $y^{n} > x$ and derive a contradiction. Let me know if you face any problem and then I can provide hints or a proper solution.

Comment: Yes, i see now my proof is a bit redundant. Good think is it is a little different from the original.  Thank you!